# multiple users updating the one form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a website that manages realworld tabletop games via a php, jquery, bootstrap and mysql setup.

It has been running very well for a number of years, but I am implementing a team game concept, which allows 2 "captains" to manage the pairings at the same time. The page itself does what I want it to do when one captain does all the data entry, but it is not really optimal for both to be doing it at the same time.

[Once both players for a game have been selected the row turns green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4sIe.png)

The goal is that as a Captain selects a player from a drop down box, it should somehow update the other captains screen and vice versa.

Should I have some kind of timer going, and every X seconds refresh the page, form, etc? Has anyone done something similar to this in the past?

I am thinking of having a table in my database with each field on the form, and when it was last updated, then I could loop through the table and only update the most recent ones, but I feel this could be an extra layer that just may be over complicating it.

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: This question is pretty broad and open to opinions on the matter.  But I would point you towards websockets for this.  https://socket.io/ is the primary js library for this that I know of, but there are probably others.

Comment: thanx Taplar, I guess I didn't know where to start looking, so it had to be a broad question. However socket.io is just that, a great place for me to start looking. Thanx heaps

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing the whole page is definitely possible, but I wouldn't recommend it.

You could execute an ajax call for every x second with `setInterval()`. Requesting all data from the server and see if everything is loaded. You also would have to send the new data back to the server when the player changes a field.

A better approach for this would be the usage of sockets. They synchronize data across different browsers (almost) instantly. Without the need to constantly request data from the server.

You can take a look at [socket.io](https://socket.io/) for more information. This is a javascript package to make the implementation of sockets fairly simple in javascript.